# Android 4.0 onwards OMX-IL HW Decoding from Native side

Tags: android, stagefright

Is it possible to use Android native code and OMX-IL (maybe using stagefright even) for HW decoding in Android 4.1 onward (maybe you will suggest creating an instance of OMXCodec). But I want to do my own surface allocation and handling done from the client application. The OMXCodec::Create expects a ANAtiveWindow but I want to bypass that and just use a decode function, where I would pass a buffer/eglSurface and get the decoded frame output. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JellyBean, I feel you could employ `MediaCodec` object to achieve the decoding of a frame. You could refer to the `SimplePlayer` implementation as in http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/cmds/stagefright/SimplePlayer.cpp#316 which provide you a good reference to develop your program.

Comment: Thnx! The class implementation looks like what I wanted.